# Stylesheet_link_tag does not work as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stylesheet

I am using Rails 3.1.1 and have stylesheets in my assets-folder as:

- application.css
- abc.css.scss
- def.css.scss
- etc

also in a subfolder /admin/ I have admin.css. All in all

- application.css
- admin/admin.css
- abc.css.scss
- def.css.scss
- etc.

Now, by using:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application' %>
```

...(which seems to be default) I would expect it to only load the application.css but it loads not only application.css but also abc.css.scss etc.

```
<link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/admin/admin.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/affiliate_types.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/benefits.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/buy_this_ifs.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Additionally it loads admin.css in the /admin/-subfolder. As far as I understand recursive is defaulted to false, so it shouldn't, right?

Anyway, I tried:

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', :recursive => false %>
```

which still loaded the admin/admin.css. Same result as above in other words.

If I try:

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag :all %>
```

it just loads an "all.css" that it cannot find.

I have tried variants of `:cache => true` and `:cache => false` to no avail.

My questions:

1. How do I make rails import all stylesheets (application.css, abc.css.scss etc) but NOT admin/admin.css?
2. How do I make admin.css inherit from application.css? I just want to have the unique features of the admin interface (such as a different body color) in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was due to the:

```
 *= require_tree .
```

in the application.css-file itself. I thought that didn't do anything since it was inside comment brackets.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you just saved me a world of headache. I wonder why this happens though, being commented and all.

Comment: Rails interprets these sort of magical comments. I believe it's initially for use with sass, but works for regular css files as well. To make admin.css inherit from application.css, simply require application.css from within admin.css, using these magical require comments.

Answer (score -1):

I found out my problem...

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'homepage', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

I needed to include data-turbolinks-track.

Comment: Turbolinks has nothing to do with asset paths. it could be that enabling it detected a change in the file and reloaded it, so you initially had a caching issue.